# Телеграм бот проскакивает @bot.message_handler

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

пишу бота с конечными автоматами, при возврате в главное меню по инлайн кнопке должен  создаваться новый объект и хандлеры начинаться с начала, но он возвращает меня на тот шаг где я вышел в меню код

```
class WayBill:
        def __init__(self):
                """При инициализации новой заявки очищаем все поля"""
                self.numberwb = ""
                self.datewb = ""
                self.sumwb = ""
                self.objectwb = ""
                self.primwb = ""
        
            def send(self, telegram_id):
                """Отправляем данные в Гугл таблицу"""
                cursor.execute("SELECT username FROM staff WHERE position = 'Прораб' and telegram_id=?", (telegram_id,))
                foreman = cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
                sheet = gsheets.gsAuth(workbookID=config.workbookID, sheetName='Накладные')
                paydate = str(datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))
                try:
                    appendToSheets(activesheet=sheet, paydate=paydate, waybill=self.numberwb, note=self.primwb,
                                   waybilldate=self.datewb, amount=self.sumwb, target=self.objectwb, author=foreman)
                    return 'Операция занесена'
                except Exception:
                    return 'Ошибка занесения'
    
    keyboard_to_main_menu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    Cancel_to_list_choice = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="В Главное меню", callback_data="to_list_choice")
    
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'waybill')
    def inline_waybill(call):
        global NoteWB
        NoteWB = WayBill()
        try:
            bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
        except:
            print('Не удалось удалить сообщение')
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                         "Введите номер накладной:", reply_markup=keyboard_to_main_menu)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, set_number)
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"], func=lambda message: message.chat.id in whitelist)
def set_number(message):
    numberwb = message.text
    print(numberwb)
    NoteWB.numberwb = numberwb
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id - 1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Накладная №{NoteWB.numberwb}...\nВведите дату накладной:",
                     reply_markup=keyboard_to_main_menu)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, set_date)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"], func=lambda message: message.chat.id in whitelist)
def set_date(message):
    global NoteWB
    datewb = message.text
    print(datewb)
    NoteWB.datewb = datewb
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id - 1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Накладная №{NoteWB.numberwb} от {NoteWB.datewb}...\nВведите cумму накладной:",
                     reply_markup=keyboard_to_main_menu)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, set_sum)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"], func=lambda message: message.chat.id in whitelist)
def set_sum(message):
    global NoteWB
    sumwb = message.text
    sumwb = str(sumwb).replace(',', '.')
    print(sumwb)
    NoteWB.sumwb = sumwb
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id - 1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f"Накладная №{NoteWB.numberwb} от {NoteWB.datewb} на сумму {NoteWB.sumwb}р...\nВведите название объекта",
                     reply_markup=keyboard_to_main_menu)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, set_object)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"], func=lambda message: message.chat.id in whitelist)
def set_object(message):
    global NoteWB
    objectwb = message.text
    print(objectwb)
    NoteWB.objectwb = objectwb
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id - 1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f"Накладная №{NoteWB.numberwb} от {NoteWB.datewb} на сумму {NoteWB.sumwb}р. объект: {NoteWB.objectwb}\nВведите примечание или нажмите кнопку 'Добавить без примечания'",
                     reply_markup=keyboard_send)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, set_prim)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"], func=lambda message: message.chat.id in whitelist)
def set_prim(message):
    global NoteWB
    primwb = message.text
    print(primwb)
    NoteWB.primwb = primwb
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id - 1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f"Накладная №{NoteWB.numberwb} от {NoteWB.datewb} на сумму {NoteWB.sumwb}р. объект: {NoteWB.objectwb}, Примечание: {NoteWB.primwb}\nЗапись добавлена")
    NoteWB.send(message.chat.id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     "Что сделать?",
                     reply_markup=keyboard_Choice)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в gunicorn. Из-за нескольких процессов сообщения попадали в разные и соответсвенно в тех процессорах не было запомненного шага